# PHP open external page with special header

Tags: php, header, new-window

How can I open a new window (or tab) of an external webpage with a special Header like `"Authorization:Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"` and open it normally with its full design?

Comment: try create a Hyperlink using <a> tag and attribut 'target' => '_blank'

Comment: target="_blank" will always work to open new external page.

Comment: I want to open external with special header , not normal open !

Answer (score 0):

You want the client browser to open a page with a certain header? This is not possible from server side code.

Comment: I want to redirect with special header using crul or "header" function  , this not possible too ?